# Reverse Torsion (dihedral) Angle to find coordinate point (X,Y,Z)

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, coordinate-systems

[image]

Please consider the above picture, I have two plains (Plain-MNO and Plain-NOP) with a known torsion (dihedral) angle "a", I also know the coordinates of point M, N, and O. Further I know the distance of point P to M, N and O. I need the coordinates (X, Y, Z) of point P.

Python is our domain, but we can also use other languages (C / Perl), but Python is recommended.

Further, we know the geometry, the equations and all the theory things, what we need a simple function which will take all the inputs and will return coordinates of "P" (Some vector operations are needed).

Comment: Do you have any geometric primitive function at your disposal ?

Comment: You query is not clear to me.

Comment: I mean eg: function that compute the equation of a plane containing three points

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know how to calculate the position, don't know how to implement the calculation in software, or both?

Comment: both to me , still unanswered